# Sending an email with headers via wp_mail

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I need to send mail from wordpress powered site. I am using wp_mail. I want to add $header to the mail so it would say who send it.

When i use $headers like that:

```
$headers = "From: $name <$email>"
```

$name and $email are propper variables*

And then

```
if (wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers) ) {
    echo 'Thanks!';
} else {
    echo 'Error!';
```

I always get "Error!" and no mail. I've read about 'wp_mail_from' and 'wp_mail_from_name' but I dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using $headers as an array? Try this instead of the current $headers line you have:

`$headers[] = 'From: $name <$email>' . "\r\n";`

Comment: Nope, didnt help. But i found that:
 `$headers .= "Reply-To: \"$name\" <$email>\r\n"`
works and its enough for me right now. 
But if someone know how to enable 'From:' it would be cool.